# The argument type 'XFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Please, can anyone help rewrite this code, don't know what I'm getting wrong.

```dart
 Widget _decideImageView(){
        
        if(imageFile == null) {
        return Text("No Image Selected!");} 
        else {
        Image.file(imageFile!,width: 400,height: 400,);
        }
        return Text("No Image Selected!");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `File? imageFile;` to `XFile? imageFile;`

Use `Image.file(File(imageFile!.path),` from `dart:io`

```dart
 XFile? imageFile;
  _openCamera(BuildContext context) async {
    imageFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {});
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  Widget _decideImageView() {
    if (imageFile == null) {
      return Text("No Image Selected!");
    } else {
      return Image.file(
        File(imageFile!.path),
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Have tried the above code but still getting this error message.

Exception has occurred.
_CastError (type 'XFile' is not a subtype of type 'File?' in type cast)

Comment: Below is the code I'm working, maybe you can take a look at it to tell me where I'm making any mistake. Thank you.

Comment: do it like `File(imageFile!.path)` it shouldnt show any error

Comment: class _LandingScreenState extends State<LandingScreen> {

  File? imageFile;
  
  _openGallery(BuildContext context) async{
    final picture = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    this.setState(() {
      imageFile = picture as File?;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

Comment: need to change the file type, check update answer

Comment: _openCamera(BuildContext context) async{
    final picture = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    this.setState(() {
      imageFile = picture as File?;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

Comment: Avoid using as prefix without being sure, check update answer

Comment: Sorry for lots of question I'm asking. I'm new to flutter and still trying to understand a lot of things. 

Please, how can I go about "Use Image.file(File(imageFile!.path), from dart:io" you asked me to do? 

Every other things is showing perfectly but when I try selecting picture from the gallery it refer me back to this point "setState(() {});". 

Please help out with this. Thank you.

Comment: Two different library provides File, so you need to import dart:io, another one is `dart:html` which isnt needed here. Do you face any issue? Btw I am not getting why you used pop there, try to remove ` Navigator.of(context).pop();` if you dont like go back to previous route/page

Comment: Glad to help you can explore more on https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker